# @Retention of Java type checker annotations

Tags: java, annotations, retention, checker-framework

The Java 8 type annotations (JSR 308) allow type checkers to perform static code analysis. For example, [The Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) can check for possible *nullness* via `@NonNull` annotations.

Various projects define their own *NonNull* annotations, for example:

- `org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull`
- `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull`
- `javax.annotation.Nonnull`
- `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`
- `lombok.NonNull`
- `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull`
- etc. (see [The Checker Framework Manual, section 3.7](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-related-work))

For such annotations, I would expect the `@interface` to have [**`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#CLASS), because they are usually not needed at runtime. Most importantly, the code does not have any runtime dependencies on the respective library.

While [`org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/NonNull.html) follows this approach, most other *NonNull* annotations, like `javax.annotation.Nonnull` (JSR 305) and [`org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/NonNull.html) itself, have [**`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME). Is there any particular reason for the `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` in these annotations?

---

Clarification: The Checker Framework supports annotations in comments for backward compatibility. However, using those in Java 8 just to avoid runtime dependencies seems like a dirty hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good question.

For the purpose of static checking at compile time, `CLASS` retention would be sufficient.  Note that `SOURCE` retention would not be sufficient, because of separate compilation:  when type-checking a class, the compiler needs to read the annotations on libraries that it uses, and separately-compiled libraries are available to the compiler only as class files.

The annotation designers used `RUNTIME` retention to permit tools to perform run-time operations.  This could include checking the annotations (like an assert statement), type-checking of dynamically-loaded code, checking of casts and `instanceof` operations, resolving reflection more precisely, and more.  Not many such tools exist today, but the annotation designers wanted to accommodate them in the future.

You remarked that with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)`, "the code does not have any runtime dependencies on the respective library."  This is actually true with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`, too!  See this Stack Overflow question:
[Why doesn't a missing annotation cause a ClassNotFoundException at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567413/why-doesnt-a-missing-annotation-cause-a-classnotfoundexception-at-runtime) .

In summary, using `CLASS` retention costs a negligible amount of space at run time, enables more potential uses in the future, and does not introduce a run-time dependency.

In the case of the Checker Framework, it offers run-time tests such as [`isRegex(String)`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/regex/RegexUtil.html#isRegex-java.lang.String-).  If your code uses such methods, your code will be dependent on the Checker Framework runtime library (which is smaller than the entire Checker Framework itself and has a more permissive license).

Comment: Related note for mocking annotated classes with mockito (version 2.2.0): 
While RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME means that an annotation present in the binary doesn't have to be available at runtime, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152174 causes a NullPointerException in Java 8 when mocking an annotated class for which the annotation is not available on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Each annotation has it's purpose!

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
```

This ones is defined by the bean validation specification and is used to perform non-null check at runtime, so it needs to be retained at runtime to perform, for example, a form valdiation ...

@RetentionPolicy.SOURCE => usually used for documentation
@RetentionPocily.CLASS => allow to give some information to the compiler but not the JVM (for example, to perform code generation during compilation)
@RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME => allow to retrieve annotation information at the JVM level (so at runtime).

Regards,

Loïc

Comment: Yes `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` has a runtime purpose.   

But `javax.annotation.Nonnull` and `org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull` have no runtime purpose IMO.

Comment: There is no global answer to your question, it's up to the creator of the annotation to define if it needs to be retained in runtime or not.
See this SOW thread for some hint : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810030/javax-annotation-nonnull-vs-assert